# How to handle printf(" ", ) and scanf(" ") with frama-c command?

Tags: linux, graph, frama-c

I am using this code to generate the control flow graph of a C program. It is working fine for all the function except built-in function like `printf` and `scanf`. What can I change in this code to output the built in function as it is?

```
open Cil
open Cil_types
let print_stmt out =
function
| Instr i -> !Ast_printer.d_instr out i
| Return _ -> Format.pp_print_string out "<return>"
| Goto _ -> Format.pp_print_string out "<goto>"
| Break _ -> Format.pp_print_string out "<break>"
| Continue _ -> Format.pp_print_string out "<continue>"
| If (e,_,_,_) -> Format.fprintf out "if %a" !Ast_printer.d_exp e
| Switch(e,_,_,_) -> Format.fprintf out "switch %a" !Ast_printer.d_exp e
| Loop _ -> Format.fprintf out "<loop>"
| Block _ -> Format.fprintf out "<enter block>"
| UnspecifiedSequence _ -> Format.fprintf out "<enter unspecified sequence>"
| TryFinally _ | TryExcept _ -> Format.fprintf out "<try>"

class print_cfg out =
object
inherit Visitor.frama_c_inplace

method vstmt_aux s =
Format.fprintf out "s%d@[[label=\"%a\"]@];@\n" s.sid print_stmt s.skind;
List.iter 
  (fun succ -> Format.fprintf out "s%d -> s%d;@\n" s.sid succ.sid)
  s.succs;
DoChildren
method vglob_aux g =
match g with
  | GFun(f,loc) ->
      Format.fprintf out "@[<hov 2>subgraph cluster_%a {@\n\
                         graph [label=\"%a\"];@\n" 
        Cil_datatype.Varinfo.pretty f.svar
        Cil_datatype.Varinfo.pretty f.svar;
      ChangeDoChildrenPost([g], fun g -> Format.fprintf out "}@\n@]"; g)
  | _ -> SkipChildren

 method vfile f =
 Format.fprintf out "@[<hov 2>digraph cfg {@\n";
 ChangeDoChildrenPost (f,fun f -> Format.fprintf out "}@."; f)
 end

 let run () =
 let chan = open_out "cfg.out" in
 let fmt = Format.formatter_of_out_channel chan in
 Visitor.visitFramacFileSameGlobals (new print_cfg fmt) (Ast.get())

 let () = Db.Main.extend run
```

Comment: What it is exactly the issue? I had a quick look at your code and I don't see anything that would cause trouble with variadic functions. Could you post a C example, with the difference between expected and actual output?

Comment: if i use statement printf("HELLO %d"); then after loading the script while trying to covert it into png using dot -Tpng it gives error  label=printf("HELLO %d");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not related to variadic functions per se, but instead to literal strings. You must quote them, as otherwise `dot` thinks the label has ended. Try replacing

```
Format.fprintf out "s%d@[[label=\"%a\"]@];@\n" s.sid print_stmt s.skind;
```

by

```
Format.fprintf out "s%d@[[label=%S]@];@\n" s.sid (Pretty_utils.to_string print_stmt s.skind);
```

(Notice the `%S`, that outputs a quoted string.)

Comment: How can I learn  this language to make control flow graph more understandable? @Boris Yakobowski

Comment: Which language do you mean ? Dot, OCaml, or OCaml's sublanguage for `fprintf` ?

Comment: Ocaml , I want to generate the graph which is more user friendly , @Boris Yakobowski

Comment: Sorry to trouble you , but when i am using "frama-c -load-script cfg_print.ml test.c " to load this script ,it is working fine but when i am trying to execute this command using shell_exec(' frama-c -load-script cfg_print.ml'.escapeshellarg(test.c)); using php its not working. Please help @  Boris Yakobowsk